# Expanding & Collapsing 1 Tableview Section with 1 row

Tags: swift, uitableview

My tableview consist of 2 sections. I want to expand and collapse only 1 section. Currently I can collapse it but am getting errors when trying to expand it.

I would post an image to show the UI but the new question interface is super confusing on how to embed an image from your pc into the question. You used to be able to easily drag an image into the question.

```
var section1 = ExpandableCell(isExpanded: true, section: ["Section 1"])

@objc func handleExpandClose(button: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    let isExpanded = section1.isExpanded
    section1.isExpanded = !isExpanded
    if isExpanded {
        section1.section.removeAll()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } else {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandClose), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return section1.section.count
    }

    return 1
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'  I understand it has to do with numbers in row but am having trouble wrapping my head around a fix for this.

Comment: When you collapse, the count of section1.section becomes 0, because you removed all the items in the [String]. When you expand, where do you add anything to that array? So, in the else part of the isExpanded conditional, you'll need a `section1.section.append("some string")`, or else it stays with count == 0 as the error message suggests.

Comment: @KennyHo Take a look in this library https://github.com/Vkt0r/AccordionSwift that can facilitate your life and this question https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2695387+expand&mixed=0

Comment: use table view begin updates and end updates methods.